# javascript array counting sparse indexed element

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, I have an array `anArray` that could have several states like the following:

- the array might be empty `[]`
- the array might be containing exactly one value `[2]`
- the array might be containing multiple value but not in ordered index `[2, empty, 5, empty, empty, 10]` (obtained from chrome's console)

I want to count the exact number of element in that array, so:

- `[]` should give me `0`
- `[2]` should give me `1`
- `[2, empty, 5, empty, empty, 10]` should give me `3`

How can I achieve this?

What I already tried, say if the array's state was `[2, empty, 5, empty, empty, 10]`:

- accessing `anArray[1]` gave me error `"ReferenceError: element is not defined"`, because I think the index of `1` did not even existed.
- did compare eaach element with `null` or `undefined`, but like before, accessing empty element like `anArray[1]` will throw an error/warning before the evaluation
- used `in` like `1 in anArray`, but it gave me true everytime even if the element is empty.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Let me attach the snap I take directly from chrome console
[Please look me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77411.png)

Comment: What does it mean _empty_? Is it `undefined` or `null` or `''`?

Comment: You can filter: `arr.filter(v=>v!==undefined).length` (or use `reduce` if you want something more efficient).

Comment: ... or is it *unset* ?

Comment: @TheReason I don't think it is either `undefined` or `null`. It is just not there. The index skips at the _empty_.

Comment: "accessing anArray[1] gave me error" *What* error?

Comment: There's no way accessing a missing element gives an error in JS

Comment: @str Sorry for the ambiguity, I updated the question. Thankyou.

Comment: @Nina Scholz Thankyou for marking the duplicate and I'm sorry. The referenced question asnwers well to my problem. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
anArray.reduce(c => c + 1,0)
```

As every array method skips unset array positions, this will count all elements of a sparse array

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This answer assumes too much about the real question, and isn't clearly explained, but it's interesting.

Comment: This answers my problem exactly. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @rahmatNazali youre welcome :)

Comment: @JonasW. I really learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: I love a good lambda expression! Bravo.

Comment: glad to hear :)

Comment: Why would you write "[2, empty, 5, empty, empty, 10] should give me 3" when you actually wanted to add the numbers together? :/

Comment: @DominicTobias i dont get your point

Comment: Nvm at a glance I thought your code was counting values but I just noticed it's counting occurrence sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [2, , 5, , , 10]
const n = arr.filter(x => x).length
console.log(n)
```